# MacOs Diskutil cant resize APFS

Tags: macos, disk-utility, bootcamp, disk-space

[image]

[image]

How i can add free space to Container disk2 (disk0s4)?

Comment: Do you have a backup? Since the free space is not contiguous, you’ve got several indirect choices to make.

Comment: @bmike  , The data is all saved to an external drive. Interested in how I can solve this problem.
It seems to me that everything is due to the fact that the free space in front of the partition (